# Solr query via CURL - [globbing] bad range in column

Tags: curl, solr

I have a core in Solr named `test`. I have ingested 2 nested JSON documents in it. They are as follows:

```
{"id":1, "path":"1.parent", "_childDocuments_":{"path":"2.parent.child"}}
```

And

```
{"id":2, "path":"1.parent", "_childDocuments_":{"path":"2.parent.child"}}
```

When I query `test` core via browser for response in a parent-child relationship I correct repsonse:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/test/select?fl=*,[child%20parentFilter=path:1.parent%20childFilter=path:2.parent.child]&indent=on&q={!parent%20which=%22path:1.parent%22}&wt=json

{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":2,
    "params":{
      "q":"{!parent which=\"path:1.parent\"}",
      "indent":"on",
      "fl":"*,[child parentFilter=path:1.parent childFilter=path:2.parent.child]",
      "wt":"json"}},
  "response":{"numFound":2,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "id":"1",
        "path":["1.parent"],
        "_childDocuments_.path":["2.parent.child"],
        "_version_":1565913168462479360},
      {
        "id":"2",
        "path":["1.parent"],
        "_childDocuments_.path":["2.parent.child"],
        "_version_":1565913171789611008}]
  }}
```

But when I try to run same query via `curl` it shows error:

```
$ curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/test/select?fl=*,[child%20parentFilter=path:1.parent%20childFilter=path:2.parent.child]&indent=on&q={!parent%20which=%22path:1.parent%22}&wt=json'
curl: (3) [globbing] bad range in column 46
```

I am not able to understand via. Although, I can understand that `curl` request is giving error on `column 46` which is a special character `[` in the `http` request. But, then how it working in browser and how can we make this request working via `curl` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just pass to curl the parameter `-g/--globoff`

> This  option  switches  off  the "URL globbing parser". When you set
> this option, you can   specify URLs that contain the letters {}[]
> without having them being interpreted by  curl   itself.  **Note  that
> these  letters  are not normal legal URL contents but they should be
>
> encoded according to the URI standard.**

On the other hand the browser silently converts the letters `{}[]` and submit the query successfully.

So all you have to do is use the curl parameter or encode the query string before the submit.

I suppose in this way should work:

`curl --globoff 'http://localhost:8983/solr/test/select?fl=*,[child%20parentFilter=path:1.parent%20childFilter=path:2.parent.child]&indent=on&q={!parent%20which=%22path:1.parent%22}&wt=json'`